# Set TargetName dynamically and DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames in XAML

Tags: wpf, dynamic, storyboard, target

i want to know how to change target name dynamicaly with same animation

Please find Below is my code of WPF for xaml and c# code

XAML code

```
<Storyboard x:Key="deepanshu">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames x:Name="gupta" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                   Storyboard.TargetName="image1">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0.641"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                   Storyboard.TargetName="image1">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0.689"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                   Storyboard.TargetName="image1">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="-1"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)"
                                   Storyboard.TargetName="image1">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0.5"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

---

c#

```
Storyboard sb = (Storyboard)FindResource("deepanshu");
```

Now how to change storyboaname from image1 to image2?

Thanks
Regards,
Deepanshu

Answer (score 1):

```
Storyboard sb = (Storyboard)FindResource("deepanshu");
foreach (var animation in sb.Children)
{
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(animation, "image2");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What H.B. said is working perfectly fine. In XAML put storyboard without specifying TargetName like this

```
<Storyboard x:Key="OpacityUpAnim">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:1.3">
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut" />
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>
</Storyboard>
```

for C# I wrote a custom function to call Animation.

```
private void RunStoryBoardFromName(string animName, string targetName = null)
    {
        Storyboard storyBoard = (Storyboard)this.Resources[animName];
        if (targetName != null)
        {
            foreach (var anim in storyBoard.Children)
            {
                Storyboard.SetTargetName(anim, targetName);
            }
        }
        storyBoard.Begin();
    }
```

then I called it in C# like

```
RunStoryBoardFromName("OpacityUpAnim", "PopupGrid");
```